# Apply a particular validation rule on a specific input, only if another input is also present and set to a specific value

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-validation

To put it simply, what I want to do is to check if the value of a particular input `exists` in the database, but I want the `exists` rule to be applied only if another input is also present with a specific value.

For example, let’s say I have a form with a select named `type` and a text field named `id`.

```
<select name="type">
    <option value="0">Type0</option>
    <option value="1">Type1</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="id">
```

If the `type` is present and equals to `1` I want to check if the `id` input `exists` in the database table `users`, otherwise the `exists` rule to not be applied at all, while the rest of the validation rule to be applied as normal.

**Edit:**

Preferably, I'd like to use a form request for doing the validation. Can that be achieved using a form request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [conditionally](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#conditionally-adding-rules) add rules as:

```
$v = Validator::make(...);

$v->sometimes('id', 'exists:table,column', function($input) {
     return $input->get('type') == 1;
});
```

**Update**

For `form request` you can do as:

```
$rules = [
    ...,
];

if ($this->get('type') == 1){
    if (isset($rules['id'])){
        $rules['id'] .= '|exists:table,column';
    }
    else {
        $rules['id'] = 'exists:table,column';
    }
}

return $rules;
```

Comment: Thank you, that exactly answers my question. Do you know though if the same thing can be achieved inside a form request?

Comment: I just discovered that it could also be done by overriding the `validate` method of the `ValidatesWhenResolvedTrait` trait, but your solution is much more elegant so I'll use that.

Comment: I made a small addition to your answer because at its previus form it was overwriting any predefined rules for the target field. Now it checks first if any rules about that field already exist and if yes it appends the `exists` rule to them.

Comment: Yes, you are right. If you want then you can suggest edit for the answer.

Comment: Ok thanks, I was checking that on my phone so didn't notice that.